# Selenium Webdriver not responding to 2nd page code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Tried login to gmail from google homepage through Selenium WebDriver. Google page is working fine.After clicking Sign In button, No operations is being done by Selenium.

code used:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("farha");
```

I am using Firefox 52.0.1 version, selenium 3.3.0 and Eclipse 4.6

Comment: Can you provide some more information as: 1. After the page Google.co.in loads what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: steps I followed:    1. click on google homepage 2. click on Sign In button 3. Enter Username as farha.    Problem is  in username text box "farha" is not entering.

Comment: did it work now? Where are you stuck now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Please take a minute to properly format the code. Also add the intended steps in your scenario so we can follow what you are attempting. What does "No operations" mean? The browser didn't even navigate to google? Add more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do :

1. Use the below mentioned code:

WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70")).click(); // I suppose here you are clicking the SignIn button so check the id of the link carefully

driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("farha");

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your code. If you need help, take a look at the help topics on formatting code.